# Select url from database into php variable

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    try{
        include("dbconnectie.php");
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id_img = '3'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $image = $result['img_url'];
        echo "<table>";
            foreach($result as &$data) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["brand"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["model"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["cond"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["price"] . "</td>";
                    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $data["image"] ).'"/>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <a src='<?php echo $image; ?>' border='0'></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

in line 7 u can see that i'm trying to define $image as the url that's saved in the database so i could use it all the way at the bottom to project it as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble with PDO queries (Notice: Undefined index)](//stackoverflow.com/q/31634052)

Comment: I don't believe an a element can have a src attribute.